# AdMob test ads not working - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, adwhirl

I am using AdMob through AdWhirl and last week running in the simulator showed test ads from both AdMob and iAd.
Nothing has changed in my AdWhirl code, and test mode is still on, yet I no longer get test ads from AdMob. Every now and then I get a proper ad. Test ads from iAd are fine.

I have tried the AdWhirl and AdMob forums but my posts never get posted!

Anyone know what the problem could be?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you may need to modify the code in the AdWhirlAdapterGoogleAdMobAds.m. The line where it turns on test mode

```
[additional setObject:@"on" forKey:@"adtest"];
```

Should probably be changed to

```
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,                                           
                       nil];
```

It looks like the method of using "adtest" in the `additionalParamters` property of `GADRequest` doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Of course, this also assumes you've overridden the `adWhirlTestMode` method in your class that is an `AdWhirlDelegate`.

Comment: Thanks, I shall try this in the morning. I have adWhirlTestMode set to YES.

Comment: Excellent RajPara, this fixed it.
You are right that adtest parameter isn't working any more.
I'm now getting test ads again.
I trust I can leave this change in place when I finally distro my app, and just remove the adWhirlTestMode.

Answer (score 1):

if you changed nothing..then it is from there side..try changing priorities..and traffic of the ads network in adwhirl.

Comment: I've disabled all networks apart from AdMob. I now get no ads, unless every now and then a proper ad is available.
It's frustrating that I can't talk to anyone at AdMob as they refer to their forum, yet you can't post on their forum without admin authorisation.

Has anyone else had problems like this with AdMob lately?

Comment: from what i have experienced there are no test ads in admob..maybe there are ..but in my experience i had both iAd and admob.. and iAd always showed up with test advertisement since it was a higher priority.. but when i changed the priority . there were admob ads coming up..just that could not earn money with them.(this is the time when i was testing the app in development). So i want to ask your problem is ads are coming but not always?

Comment: Yes I am getting ads but not regular (which I guess is the usual behaviour). However last week I was getting test ads from AdMob.
It said it was a test ad and always came, and if you clicked on it it showed some google stuff.
Now the test ads have stopped.

Comment: well..you ware worried for test ads coming and now stopping.. i didn't have test ads in the first place..yet i submitted and am earning money using admob :)

Comment: Ok thanks. Maybe i'm worried over nothing. I didn't want to get punished for requesting proper ads in the simulator.
From what i've been reading, the AdMod SDK has a setting to automatically detect the simulator, so it must definately be a problem their end.
Thanks